# How can I download an XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Given this URL:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=1253

How can I download the resulting XML file and have it loaded to memory so I can grab information from it using Linq?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Load string:

```
string xml = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

Then load into XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

For example:

```
[Test]
public void TestSample()
{
    string url = "http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=1253";
    string xml;
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        xml = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    }

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    // in the result profile with id name is 'Nate'
    string name = doc.XPathSelectElement("/ipb/profile[id='1253']/name").Value;
    Assert.That(name, Is.EqualTo("Nate"));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that doc doesn't have a XPathSelectElement method. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, It's an XML LINQ extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx
It needs to add `using System.Xml.Linq` to imports.

Comment: you also need `using System.Xml.XPath;`

Answer (score 42):

Why complicate things? This works:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=1253");
```

Comment: What about `DownloadStringAsync`? is that better way to handle downloading?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
Stream data = client.OpenRead ("http://example.com");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
Console.WriteLine (s);
data.Close ();
reader.Close ();
```

Though using [`DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) is easier:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string s = client.DownloadString("http://example.com");
```

You can load the resulting string into an `XmlDocument`.